# MongoDb aggregation merges the output in a single array while i need as separate records

Tags: mongodb

Trying to fetch records through MongoDb aggregation.

Have attached code : [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUEZR.png

Output coming is:
Participants:

```
0: { Name: [Record 1, Record 2, Record 3], Value: [Record A, Record B, Record C]
```

Desired output is:
Participants:

```
0: { Name: Record 1, Value: Record A}
1: {Name: Record 2, Value: Record B}
2: {Name: Record 3, Value: Record C}
```

Comment: What is the input, can you share some sample input ?

Comment: Participants was an array, so i was supposed to unwind it first before processing.

Comment: Got solved, thanks for your support